# How to merge records in SQL when the dates are overlapping

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to merge records in SQL when the dates are overlapping?

| Name | Start date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1-mar-2023 | 5-may-2023 |
| Bob | 1-may-2023 | 25-may-2023 |

I want to merge records where there is an overlap.

Expected output

| Name | start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1-mar-2023 | 25-may-2023 |

Comment: Use the group by based on the start date

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316064/aggregate-overlapping-date-intervals, sql server version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316064/aggregate-overlapping-date-intervals to Snowflake (thanks Serg).

The trick is really interesting: Have all start dates and end dates in one column, add 1 when you see a start date, subtract 1 when you see an end date. That running counts shows 0 every time there's an interval closed, covering all openings and closings within it - with `cte3` grouping starts and ends:

```sql
with data(account_id, start_date, end_date) as (
    select * from values
    ('A','2019-06-20','2019-06-29'),
    ('A','2019-06-25','2019-07-25'),
    ('A','2019-07-20','2019-08-26'),
    ('A','2019-12-25','2020-01-25'),
    ('A','2021-04-27','2021-07-27'),
    ('A','2021-06-25','2021-07-14'),
    ('A','2021-07-10','2021-08-14'),
    ('A','2021-09-10','2021-11-12'),
    ('B','2019-07-13','2020-07-14'),
    ('B','2019-06-25','2019-08-26')
),
cte1 AS (
    SELECT account_id, start_date the_date, 1 weight
    FROM data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT account_id, end_date, -1
    FROM data
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT account_id, 
           the_date, 
           SUM(weight) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id 
                             ORDER BY the_date, weight DESC) weight
    FROM cte1
),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT account_id, 
           the_date,
           SUM(CASE WHEN weight = 0 
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id 
                               ORDER BY the_date DESC) group_no
    FROM cte2
)
SELECT account_id, 
       MIN(the_date) start_date,
       MAX(the_date) end_date
FROM cte3
GROUP BY account_id, group_no
ORDER BY 1,2
```

[image]